# recursively diff two directories ignoring a single word

Tags: diff

I would like to diff two directories recursively, ignoring one particular string replacement.

For example, in one directory, some files contain the string "abcd" whereas in the other directory "abcd" has been renamed "wxyz" in those same files. I would like to see all differences between the two directories except for the renaming of "abcd" to "wxyz".

In this case the replacement length is actually the same as the original length ("abcd" and "wxyz"), although a generic solution for different string lengths would also be interesting.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried? How would you go about it without ignoring the replacement?

Comment: So far I have tried `diff -r folder1 folder2`, but it produces too many pages of output. I thought of piping it to `grep -v "abcd|wxyz"` but that would ignore too much (for example lines that contain those strings but have another difference). I also tried the `-I` option but it didn't seem to have any effect. I also saw a related answer about using sed to replace lines beforehand, but that only works for a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about it is to preprocess one of the set of files (your question states that all folder1's files might have *abcd* and folder2's files might have *wxyz*.

For example `find` can do the file searching inside one the trees, say *folder1*, and feed that to a script.

Inside the script you run the substitution on the input file and pipe the result to diff, that will compare its *standard input* with the corresponding file on the other tree.

I am assuming you have the set of files on both trees, if that's not the case you can add code to deal with it (there also flags in `diff` that might help).

A minimum version would look like this (you can add multiple substitutions for example). Note that you also have to make sure the substituting code does what you need to do, for example only change words and not substrings).

```
find folder1 -type f -printf "%P\n" |
while read myfile
do
    sed 's/abcd/wxyz/g' folder1/$myfile | diff -u folder2/$myfile -
done
```

There might be more concise ways, but this shows clearly the places where you could add some logic.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I think there's an extra `sed` in `sed sed`

Comment: Yes, corrected.